# Testing HOC with Recompose

Tags: reactjs, testing, higher-order-components, recompose

I'm having some troubles testing that a prop is fired on my HOC.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose, lifecycle } from 'recompose';

import { fetchCurrentUser } from '../../actions/users';
import { getUser } from '../../reducers/users';
import User from '../../models/User';

export default Component => compose(
  connect(state => ({
    user: getUser(state),
  }),
  { fetchCurrentUser }),
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      if (this.props.user instanceof User) return;
      this.props.fetchCurrentUser();
    },
  }),
)(Component);
```

What I'd like to know is whether or not `fetchCurrentUser` is trigger when `user` is NOT a User instance.

So far I have that in my test:

```
it.only('fetches user if user is not a User instance', () => {
  const setup = () => {
  const props = {
    user: 'string',
    fetchCurrentUser: jest.fn(),
   };
   const enzymeWrapper = mounting(props);

   return {
     props,
      enzymeWrapper,
    };
  };

  // That returns 0 so false         
  expect(setup().props.fetchCurrentUser.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
});
```

It seems like I can't replace the props doing it this way. If I log `this.props` in the lifecycle method, I never see `user: 'string'`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to shallow mount the component in order to test its functionality.

```
it.only('fetches user if user is not a User instance', () => {
  const setup = () => {
  const props = {
    user: 'string',
    fetchCurrentUser: jest.fn(),
   };
   // shallow render the component
   const enzymeWrapper = shallow(<Component {...props} />)

   return {
      props,
      enzymeWrapper,
    };
  };

  expect(setup().props.fetchCurrentUser.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. That still doesn't exchange `fetchCurrentUser` that is on the HOC for the mock one that I pass in the test. I tried using `.dive()` a few times on the shallow component, then I see the code being reached within `componentDidMount` but the function is not the mocked one

Comment: it seems that, as `connect` passes that prop to the next HOC, it takes precedence over the prop passed in the test...

Comment: @GotTheFeverMedia, yes that would happen and in order for the test to work, you could probably split your component without connect separately and test it out

Comment: Ok so, your idea worked out, somehow... :D I'll post the full answer, but vote yours as the right one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK so, with [shubham-khatri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928186/shubham-khatri)'s help, here's what I did to make it work.

Separated the component into 2 different ones, and tested the one with the call only. That way I could mock the passed props from the test.

Component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose, lifecycle } from 'recompose';

import { fetchCurrentUser } from '../../actions/users';
import { getUser } from '../../reducers/users';
import User from '../../models/User';

const Connected = connect(state => ({
  user: getUser(state),
}),
{ fetchCurrentUser });

export const Enhanced = lifecycle({
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.user instanceof User) return;

    this.props.fetchCurrentUser();
  },
});

export default Component => compose(
  Connected,
  Enhanced,
)(Component);
```

Test:

```
describe('Fetching user', () => {
    const setup = (moreProps) => {
      const props = {
        fetchCurrentUser: jest.fn(),
        ...moreProps,
      };

      const EnhancedStub = compose(
        Enhanced,
      )(Component);

      const enzymeWrapper = shallow(
        <EnhancedStub {...props} />,
      );

      return {
        props,
        enzymeWrapper,
      };
    };

    it('fetches user if user is not a User instance', () => {
      expect(setup().props.fetchCurrentUser.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
    });

    it('does NOT fetch user if user is a User instance', () => {
      expect(setup({ user: new User({ first_name: 'Walter' }) }).props.fetchCurrentUser.mock.calls.length).toEqual(0);
    });
  });
```

Hope that helps someone.